I have heard that till age of 14 all sins are not counted but some people say it is 12 years of age
I have heard that till 14 years of age all sins
are not written in the yum Raja's record but I wanted to confirm that this age is 14 or 12

I have also heard from saints that it is till age of 14.
maryādāṁ sthāpayāmy adya loke dharmaphalodayām ā caturdaśamād varṣān na bhaviṣyati pātakam pareṇa kurvatām evaṁ doṣa eva bhaviṣyati
I HEREBY ESTABLISH AS A PRINCIPLE OF JUSTICE THAT HENCEFORTH THERE WILL BE NO HEAVY SIN CONSIDERED FOR CHILDREN UP TO FOURTEEN YEARS OF AGE. AFTER THAT THEY WILL BE HELD RESPONSIBLE FOR THEIR OFFENSES. (108. 13)
Source:- https://www.vina.cc/2015/02/21/the-story-of-mandavya-muni/
